# Логирование данных влияет на скорость исполнения программы?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.Есть у меня некая привычка логировать всё подряд ,прям каждый шажек в программе. Может ли это сильно сказаться на производительности программы?
Под логгированием иммею ввиду `Log.d()`

Comment: эм... да. Любой исполняющийся кусок кода потребляет системные ресурсы как бы :)

Comment: @rjhdby Ну  это из соображений понятно)меня более интересует сильно ли*

Comment: Вот еще в тему борьбы с логами в релизе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретных цифр я не нашел (точнее нашел, но [источник](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ai0DBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=android%20log%20overhead&source=bl&ots=hCSpXJKJ4C&sig=v-FsWS9EVySeoaUQ5KcTwYQfx1M&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2x43ypujWAhXiE5oKHYIxDKMQ6AEIUDAF#v=onepage&q=android%20log%20overhead&f=false) так себе, там говорится об оверхеде в 0.4%-7.5% потребления батареи при скорости логирования 60КБ/с)

Если же исходить из документации, то там можно прочитать такое:

> The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is ERROR, WARN,
>   INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE. **Verbose should never be compiled into an
>   application except during development**. Debug logs are compiled in but
>   stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info logs are always kept.

и еще

> Tip: Don't forget that when you make a call like
>
> `Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);`
>
> that when you're building the string to pass
>   into Log.d, the compiler uses a StringBuilder and at least three
>   allocations occur: the StringBuilder itself, the buffer, and the
>   String object. Realistically, there is also another buffer allocation
>   and copy, and even more pressure on the gc. That means that if your
>   log message is filtered out, you might be doing significant work and
>   incurring significant overhead.

Тут внимания привлекают слова `significant overhead` (значительные накладные расходы)

Answer (score 3):

Сильно/слабо, - это субъективные оценочные суждения.

Сюда следует привнести элемент дифф.диагностики:

1. Можно посмотреть сколько уходит времени на выполнение основных алгоритмов программы. Взять `currentTimeMillis()` на входе и на выходе, получить разницу. Сделать это с логами и без них.
2. Посмотреть в каком-нибудь диспетчере задач, как работает программа с логами и без них.
3. Прогнать программу через [профайлер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) с логами и без них.

Думаю, применив такой подход, ты сможешь увидеть как логирование влияет на производительность.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно влияет. Чтобы исключить влияние избыточных логов на скорость исполнения я обычно делаю так:

```
public static final boolean DEBUG=true;

if(DEBUG) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Blah-blah");
}
```

Когда готовится релиз, переменную `DEBUG=false` и компилятор уже сам вырежет код вызова логгера вместе с `if`'ом - можно это даже сделать через скрипты gradle. В общем идея то понятна. В дебаг версии все обложено логами, а в релизной версии ненужные логи вырезаются.

Comment: `BuildConfig.DEBUG` уже те в моде? :)

Comment: Почему не в моде? У меня так и написано `DEBUG=BuildConfig.DEBUG`